# Rails 5: Sort by date, THEN group by a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

## This is my example history table.

```
id |    time   | price
1  | 1-02-17   | 15.99
1  | 1-03-17   | 15.99
1  | 1-04-17   | 15.99
1  | 1-05-17   | 20.99
1  | 1-06-17   | 20.99
1  | 1-07-17   | 15.99
1  | 1-08-17   | 15.99
```

## I want to get an output similar to this:

```
1-02-17 | 15.99
1-05-17 | 20.99
1-07-17 | 15.99
```

Essentially I want to group the prices AFTER sorting by date.

Can this be done with rails?

Comment: Is it normal that the ID is always 1? An Id should be unique so this is weird to me.
If I properly understand what you try to do is: find for each price its lowest date. Correct?

Comment: @StephanePaquet It's the product ID, so it's non-unique here. I basically check the price of product id 1 every day, and then I want to graph it. In order to graph it, I want the above output.

Comment: But why `1-02-17` with `15.99` rather than `1-03-17`? Are you trying to find the earliest date for each price as @StephanePaquet thinks? You might want to look at window functions if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @muistooshort What I'm really after is simply a way to exclude the repeat prices. I want a way to tell a product was priced at $15.99 from 1/02/17-1/04/17, at $20.99 from 1/05/17 to 1/06/17, and at $15.99 from 1/07/17-1/08/17 so the data can be graphed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of price points are not high, you can get fetch the records from db and do this:

```
price_ranges, prev_price = {}, nil
ProductHistory.where(product_id: 1).order(:date).find_each do |history|
 price_ranges[history.date] = history.price if history.price != prev_price
 prev_price = history.price
end
```

At the end of this loop, you would get:

```
{ "1-02-17": 15.99, "1-05-17": 20.99, "1-07-17": 15.99 }
```

Note: the key would be `Date` object instead of string if db column in `datetime`.

If number of records are high they I would suggest doing it in your db. This question looks very similar to your use case and if you have mysql then you can use it off-the-self
[How to eliminate only continuous duplicates but not all duplicates in a select query (MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292361/how-to-eliminate-only-continuous-duplicates-but-not-all-duplicates-in-a-select-q)