# How to eliminate only continuous duplicates but not all duplicates in a select query (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

01-Jul-17      100
02-Jul-17      100
03-Jul-17      300
04-Jul-17      300
05-Jul-17      500
06-Jul-17      500
07-Jul-17      300
08-Jul-17      400
09-Jul-17      100
10-Jul-17      100

What I want to output is (in this order) by eliminating the continuous duplicates but not all duplicates:
100
300
500
300
400
100

I cannot select Distinct, as it will eliminate the second instances of 300, 100. Is there a way to achieve this result in MySQL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the previous value.  If the dates really have no gaps or duplicates, just do:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.col1 = date_add(tprev.col1, interval 1 day)
where tprev.col2 is null or tprev.col2 <> t.col2;
```

EDIT:

If the dates don't meet these conditions, then you can use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@v = col2, @rn + 1,
                        if(@v := col2, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @v := 0, @rn := 0) params
      order by t.col1
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Note that MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.  So variables should not be assigned in one expression and then used in another -- they should be assigned in a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this problem is by using session variables to track the changes of the values as ordered by your date column.  In the query below, we keep track of the value, ordered by date, and assign a row number to each group of identical value.  Then, only the first value in each group is retained.  Note that this approach is robust to any number of duplicates.  It is also robust with respect to there being gaps in your dates, so long as each record can be ordered by date.

```
SET @rn = 1;
SET @val = NULL;

SELECT t.val
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @rn:=CASE WHEN @val = val THEN @rn+1 ELSE 1 END rn,
        @val:=val AS val,
        dt
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY dt
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.dt;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of lag and lead functions.

```
select y from (select y , lag(y,1,0) over (order by x) as prev_y from t1) where y <> prev_y;
```

Comment: MySQL does not support analytic functions; your query would not run.